# C++ and Java Byte Array

Tags: java, c++

Sorry for the newbie questions. I do not have any experience in c++. I have a method in C++ that generates hash value given an input. The output is stored as `char outCode[outlen]`. I have a java method that generates hash values given an input and the output is stored as  `byte[] output`. I am sending the c++ value as a stream to java. How can I compare to check they have the same hash? Thanks,

Comment: Actually I do not want to send it as a stream. I would like to printf the c++ value and System.out the java value and figure out if they have the same hash value. Thanks.

Comment: In java you have Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[]) for comparing byte array equality. But to do this programmatically, you have to share the results somehow, like writing into a file and later read it. If you only want to check the equality by glance, print the arrays by character.

Comment: I have read in this forum that I could print the byte array in java using System.out.printf("0x%02X", output[0]);. Do you know the equivalent for the c++. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're doing.
You sound like you want to display an array of binary data in hexidecimal?

C++

```
for(int i=0; i<outlen; ++i)
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << outcode[i];
std::cout << std::dec << std::endl;
```

I don't know how to do the Java.  http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.math/Bytes2Str.html looks helpful.

Comment: Actually I have hex values stored in them. The c++ output value is defined as char outCode[outlen] and the java is stored in a byte array as byte[] output. I want to make sure that the hex output are the same for both java and c++. If we ignore the for loop, I cannot just do printf("out [0]= %c", outCode[0]); and compare with System.out.println("out [0]=" + output[0]);. So I am looking for the actual printf and System.out statement that will allow me to compare apples with apples rather than oranges. thanks

Comment: So you want to display the binary contents in hex in C++?

Answer (score 0):

You can print several bytes in C/C++ this way:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < outlen; ++i)
    printf("%02x", outCode[outlen]);
```